# How to get the rolling mean and find the percentage of Male and Female in each occupation?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
occupation  gender  number
administrator   F   36
                M   43
artist          F   13
                M   15
doctor          M   7
educator        F   26
                M   69
```

How to get the rolling mean of first 2 column and find the average of (M)male and (F)female in each occupation

```
users = pd.read_table('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/DAT8/master/data/u.user', 
                      sep='|', index_col='user_id')
users.head()
age gender  occupation  zip_code
user_id             
1   24  M   technician  85711
2   53  F   other   94043
3   23  M   writer  32067
4   24  M   technician  43537
5   33  F   other   15213
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Also better is create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Isn't rolling mean something which is calculated upon a time series? Cannot see a time column there..

Comment: find the average of (M)male and (F)female in each occupation

Comment: In general you can do something like `df..groupby(['occupation', 'gender']).mean()`. But your example seems to already be grouped by. Unless some occupations repeat, there is nothing to take the average of.

Comment: So we can better understand what your dataframe is, can you post the output of `df.index` ?

Comment: added the dataframe  index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# create a data frame and apply count to gender
gender_ocup = users.groupby(['occupation', 'gender']).agg({'gender': 'count'})

# create a DataFrame and apply count for each occupation
occup_count = users.groupby(['occupation']).agg('count')

# divide the gender_ocup per the occup_count and multiply per 100
occup_gender = gender_ocup.div(occup_count, level = "occupation") * 100

# present all rows from the 'gender column'
occup_gender.loc[: , 'gender']
```

courtesy
https://github.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/blob/master/03_Grouping/Occupation/Exercises_with_solutions.ipynb